# Prevent SeachView to Reload the activity

Tags: android, android-activity, reload, searchview

I just need the result of searchview like this:

```
searchIntent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY)
```

but I don't want it from auto-reload the activity.

Thanks!

Comment: check out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094222/android-return-search-query-to-current-activity

Comment: @brahmyadigopula Thank you! Work like the charm!