# Android App search nearby

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android app that I am attempting to determine the best way of going about a certain problem. The problem is that I would like the user to have ability to input a food choice (mexican, italian, etc), have the app google search for what's nearby. Finally return the results of that search in list format. However, I want to hide the actual google search from the user and just send them the results. Now i know how to create activities with intents and even was using this link to try using built in google search: 
[Android: Return search query to current activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094222/android-return-search-query-to-current-activity)

However,

A) is using the built in google search the best way to go about it? If so, is there a way to hide that activity from popping up and the user seeing it?

or B) is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: You can use this API: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Comment: I had looked into the google api. However, my concern was since I would need an api key and they limit the requests to so many a day. If this gets published to the play store, then won't everyone who downloads the app be using my api key? Or is there a way to get a new api key associated with their own google account?

Comment: You need to use `Google Site Search` option which is a *paid* service. You simply cannot get the power of Google search for free.. :)

Comment: Ah ok thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Foursquare API. "venues/search" endpoint will list the places nearby. If you wanna refine with category then use "venues/explore" endpoint. Of course it has a rate limit but it is quite enough for start (5000 requests hourly).

**Endpoints:**

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore

**Rate Limits**

https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/ratelimits